# How does validation work in cakePHP?

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

What will I add to the controller to display the messages and halt saving before validation is true?

```
class Rsvp extends AppModel {
var $name = 'Rsvp';
var $validate = array(
                'uname' => array(
                                'rule' => array('alphaNumeric', true),
                                'message' => 'Please enter a vlaid name that does not contain digits'),
                'uemail' => array(
                                'rule' => array('email', true),
                                'message' => 'Please supply a valid email address.')


);

}
```

Controller

```
public function add() {


    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        var_dump($this->request->data);
        $this->Rsvp->set('uname', $this->request->data['Post']['name']);
        $this->Rsvp->set('uemail', $this->request->data['Post']['emailaddress']);           
          //Begin Validation Routine
        echo 'Validation';
        var_dump($this->Rsvp->validates);


        $this->Rsvp->save();    
        /*if($this->Rsvp->save()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('You have RSVP for the event');
           // $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));              
        }
        else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to RSVP you for the event.');
        }*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
if($this->Rsvp->validates()) {
   //data validated, so save
   $this->Rsvp->save($this->data);    
}
else {
   $this->Session->setFlash(__('Fill in all required fields.', true));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `Model::save()` method will validate automatically. So, validation is done simply by trying to save:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
  if ($this->Rsvp->save($this->request->data)) {
    // validated and saved to db
  } else {
    // didn't validate or failed saving to db
  }
}
```

If you do not want to validate, then use

```
$this->Rsvp->save($this->request->data, array('validate' => false));
```

Lastly, you can manually validate by setting the data and running the `validates()` method.

```
$this->Rsvp->set('uname', $this->request->data['Post']['name']);
$this->Rsvp->set('uemail', $this->request->data['Post']['emailaddress']);
$validates = $this->Rsvp->validates();
```

If it does not validate, it will set `$this->Rsvp->validationErrors`, then set it on the controller, and the form helper will be aware of these errors and automatically display them for you.

You can read more on saving data and data validation in the book: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html